# Eclipse can't save file in webapps folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, windows-7

I try to export a `Dynamic Web Project` into `.war` file to destination  - `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps`

but the eclipse prompt the next window  -

[image]

I disabled `Read-only` box for this folder but there is still this error .

I use  - `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 1`

Answer (score 1):

It's not the problem in Eclipse itself. Try checking Properties > Security of this directory. It is most likely owned by Apache. You'll need either to log in as administrator (probably the better option) or modify permissions (probably a less good option).

Answer (score 1):

**This issue may occur if the following conditions are true:**
- You log on to Microsoft Windows by using an account that does not have administrator credentials.
- You try to save the file to a folder that only users who have administrator credentials can write to.

**To work around this issue, use one of the following methods:**
- Log on as the administrator.
- Right-click on the Drive and select Properties, then go to Security tab, and click Edit.
[image]

- A new window will open, now under ***Group and User Names***, select the user from the list whom you want to allow access to a specific folder, now under ***Permissions for Users*** check the Allow checkbox next to Modify (all other checkbox will get ticked automatically).
- Click ***OK*** and then click ***Yes*** when a Windows Security window will pops-up.
- Now click ***OK*** again, restart computer and you are done.

**You maybe try other solution:**
Enable create file in the C drive (Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8)
- Log on as the administrator
- Use Notepad, Create file ***enable_write.reg*** with content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
```

- Run file ***enable_write.reg***
- Restart computer.

Of course, **you maybe edit regedit manually**, find key: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System* and set ***EnableLUA*** to ***0***
[image]